# Matrix(Reporting Services) look alike control in WPF

Tags: wpf-controls

How can i create a Matrix look a like control in WPF?

I want to create some similar like the one displayed in the below link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334.aspx

Thanks 
Sharath

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a Data Matrix in WPF
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfMatrix.aspx

Binding a ListView to a Data Matrix
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DynamicListView.aspx